# Sometimes Market update gets stuck downloading. How can I cancel?

Tags: google-play-store, updates

Sometimes when I update an app through Market the download gets stuck at 0% or 100% and won't finish download or finish installing. The only way I've found to work around this is to uninstall the app, then reinstall from Market. Is there a better way to fix this situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the "downloads" screen, long press the app in question and click "Cancel download."  Then try to update the app again and see if it'll complete this time.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a lot of downloads stalled change the connection type between 2G and 3G/4G within

Settings > Wireless & networks > Mobile networks > Use only 2G networks > Klick the checkbox

or turn Wifi off and on again. Also this keeps your stalled downloads in queue.

Also logging out and back into GoogleTalk has proven a successful solution to this issue sometimes.

Comment: Do note that the 2G only network is only available for some phones (GSM only, I believe).  It is not available on my Motorola Droid.