# Android market - Application downloading problem

Tags: 2.2-froyo, 2.1-eclair, google-play-store

I am accessing an Android market and trying to download Free applications, when i have tried to download any application by clicking on "Install" button.

When i click on "Download" button, it always shows the downloading application with the message : "Starting Download", i am seeing this message since last 2 hours, but application is not getting donwload to my phone.

Whats the problem ?

Comment: Duplicate of: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1204/sometimes-market-update-get-stuck-downloading-how-can-i-cancel

Comment: @Bryan Denny that answer was regarding Cancel the download, whereas i want to donwload the applications but remain unsuccessful in downloading applications

Comment: That's the catch.  You have to cancel the download then try to run the update again.  See if that resolves your problem.

Comment: @Bryan Denny ya i had done the same, cancel the download and try to re-download(update) , but remain unsuccessful on HTC Hero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is redundant: Please see [this one](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1204/sometimes-market-update-get-stuck-downloading-how-can-i-cancel) for a solution.

Comment: @Keyboardsurfer not solved my problem

Comment: Ok, then you could try signing out of GoogleTalk and back in again.

Comment: @Keyboardsurfer ya i already hard-restarted the phone twice

Comment: Then there might be an issue with your accout and you should consider asking Google-Support for help.

Comment: Did you successfully cancel the download, had it disappear from the "starting download" list, and start it all over again?

Comment: Yes, by long clicking the item in the download list and then pressing on cancel.