# Calendar Bug in Android 1.6 on LG GT540

Tags: calendar, 1.6-donut

On my Wife's LG GT540, the calendar has 2x 3rd of April, as you can see in the following picture:

[image]

As funny as it is, it isn't very helpful...

I'm wondering if anyone else has heard of this and/or knows a solution?

Comment: That's...weird. What widget is that?

Comment: If you install a different calendar app or widget does it happen on those too?

Comment: Haven't got the phone near me right now, but it was whatever the default one on the phone was. I'd install another Calendar to check, but the Market won't download... http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3547/market-app-downloads-always-fails-never-starts

Answer (score 1):

If your phone is still running Donut, did you know that an Eclair (Android 2.1) update should be available for that phone, Eclair starting rolling out to the Middle East in September and the rest of the world should have had it by the end of 2010. See the [official GT540 update guide on LG's website](http://csmg.lgmobile.com:9002/csmg/popup/help_management_view.jsp?brd_seq=2641&ret=1&curPage=1). You should be able to [download the necessary LG Mobile Support Tool](http://www.lg.com/au/support/product/support-product-profile-mobile-redux.jsp?customerModelCode=GT540&matchedModelCode=1400002260&searchEngineModelCode=GT540&initialTab=documents&targetPage=support-product-profile) software from here.

I would hope that such a glaring bug has been fixed in the updated calendar/widget.