# Android Market Stopped Working

Tags: google-play-store, htc-dream, 1.6-donut

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sometimes Market update get stuck downloading, how can I cancel?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1204/sometimes-market-update-get-stuck-downloading-how-can-i-cancel)

I have Android 1.6 on original G1. I tried to install Last.FM application and it failed. Since then I always see Last.FM there in process of installation and it can't be canceled or removed or anything.

And what's worse: then installation of new application stopped working at all. Coming back always after a while with "[application] failed to download. Try again later".

Any idea, how to "unblock" the market again?

Comment: One of these previous questions sound like theycould be what you're seeing: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1204/sometimes-market-update-get-stuck-downloading-how-can-i-cancel http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3547/market-app-downloads-always-fails-never-starts http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1891/android-market-application-downloading-problem

Answer (score 4):

This might help:
Go to Settings >> Applications >> Manage Applications 
Select Market app and in the details page, press "Clear data".

I had this issue a while back and it got resolved after performing the above.